# Is DMA aware of NUMA nodes?

Tags: linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-architecture, dma, numa

Assume that we have 2 physical processor with 2 sockets connected to 2 NUMA nodes.
We also have 2 PCIe devices connected through a DMA controller to the system.
What it means when we say "the local PCIe device"? Is read/write speed different for a PCIe device when it writes to different NUMA nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer [Is CPU access asymmetric to Network card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307151/is-cpu-access-asymmetric-to-network-card/36706249#36706249) would pretty much answer your question.

1. PCIe devices are connected to one NUMA node directly, thus called
   "local PCIe device" from the NUMA node point of view.
2. Yes, there is speed difference since it needs to cross NUMA nodes.